# How to display labels in Ng2-charts without having to hover over them?

Tags: angular, ng2-charts

I have a form in which, based on an applied filter, I show a graph with information:

[image]

Currently, to visualize the label of each portion, it is necessary to hover the mouse over each one:

[image]

Is there any way to show all labels without having to hover over them?

I would greatly appreciate your prompt help, it is for my final project that I must present it on Friday 12/20/2019.

Comment: The labels are there for each color. Do you want to show the all popups without having to hover?

Comment: Use ```chartjs-plugin-datalabels```. Please check this stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-pie-template-zaykfg. Is this what you are expecting?

Comment: Thanks @Vikash , works.